# Visual Studio 2015 Code Lens References Web Site Project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, codelens

After a few days of searching I have not found any documentation to say if this is proper operation or if something is not working correctly with my VS 2015 installation.

I have a solution that contains 2 DLLs and a website.  The website is referencing the DLLs

navigate to definition (f12) from the website works fine, as well as debugging and stepping into the DLLs, so the reference is correctly setup, however, the methods accessed in the DLL show 0 references for code lens above the method name.

I have removed and added the website project, did a clean, recompiled, created a code map, created a new solution and added the project code fresh, and have reinstalled VS 2015.  None of these worked, and the reference count remains at 0.  Interestingly, methods called within a code-behind show the - references (missing) above the method names.

Does code lens just not work with website projects?

it is VB.net using .net 4.5.2  We do not have TFS

Comment: I've seen the same issue with CodeLens references and Web Site projects.  Web Application projects seem to work as expected.  I don't know whether it's a deliberately missing feature or a bug though.